# Move many large media files from Windows 10 laptop to Ubuntu Server 20.04?

Tags: server, ssh, windows-10, raid, file-sharing

I'm completely new to Linux. I built a new computer today to store all my large media files. I now want to move all these media files from my Windows 10 laptop to my new Ubuntu computer. I also want to keep the current folder structures and all the folder names, etc. I'm planning to use these media files with Plex (if that's relevant). I've already connected to my server via. SSH, so the best thing would be if there is any way to move files over the network. The drives in my server are running raid 0 (sda, sdb). This is how my folders are structured:

```
Movies/
--/movie_title (release_date)
----/movie_title (release_date).mp4
----/movie_title (release_date).en.srt
etc.
```

(450 GB in total).

Let me know if I need to provide more information on anything.
Thanks, and again, I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do a one-off copy of files rather than using samba mounts just use `scp` to do remote copy. See `man scp` but a basic recursive scp command something like:

`scp -r user@server:/source/path/files /target/path/files`

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely on the right track!

Add [Samba](https://samba.org) from the Ubuntu repositories to your Ubuntu Server machine, then the Windows machine will be able to use Windows Explorer and drag-and-drop to move files. The finer details of what files are where become irrelevant.

See [Samba's documentation](https://samba.org/samba/docs) for details, and a step-by-step tutorial at   https://linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-samba-server-file-share suggests you run

```
sudo apt install samba samba-common-bin && sudo systemctl start smbd nmbd && sudo ufw allow samba
```

to install, start Samba services, & pen up the ufw firewall (if used).  While the install runs, go to the Windows machine and do **Control Panel > System and Security > System** to check for the name of the *workgroup*  (default is WORKGROUP).

Then, decide if you want a private share (which requires a username and password to login on the Windows PC to access the files) or a public share (which does not) and follow the appropriate instructions in https://linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-samba-server-file-share

Comment: Thank you. I'm in the process of setting it up now. When I typed 'sudo adduser myname' it prompted me with 'adduser: the user myname already exists'. Should I choose a different username from what I use on my computer, or is something wrong?

Comment: That user already exists? Don't worry abt that.